# First Item in Grouped List without using Lambda's?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, distinct

Assume I have an object with "id" and "name".  My list is these items:

```
id = 1, name = "Bob"
id = 2, name = "Bob"
id = 3, name = "Chris"
id = 4, name = "Chris"
id = 5, name = "Paul"
```

How can I get a subset of that list that would return me items 1, 3 and 5 (i.e. the first occurrence of a name) but specifically without Lambda's.

I think this is the Lambda solution
`items.GroupBy(item => item.UniqueIdentifier).Distinct().Select(item => item.First()).ToList();`
but I am specifically forbidden to use Lambda's on this solution (no, this isn't at school...this is in an actual work environment)

***EDIT***
I just realized that I can probably do this in my LINQ statement that gets me this list with this code.

```
(from t in this.ObjectContext.MYTABLE
    group t by t.UniqueIdentifier into theGroup
    select theGroup.First()).ToList();
```

Would that work?

Comment: That's a **horribly** stupid rule.  Do everything you can to get rid of it.

Comment: LINQ syntax is just syntactic sugar for lambdas. If you want 100% lambda-free code, you can't use LINQ.

Comment: There is no point in calling `GroupBy().Distinct()`.

Comment: @Slaks : agreed about the rule, don't get me started.  That said, would my edited in solution work you think?

Comment: Apparently I am getting really stupid.  That LINQ I posted up is incredibly easy to test using my own example.  Duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works perfectly:

```
(from t in this.ObjectContext.MYTABLE
group t by t.UniqueIdentifier into theGroup
select theGroup.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply iterate the collection, remember all names you've seen, and whenever you see a new name, take the id.

```
var seen = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (!seen.Add(item.name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.id);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
```

Comment: Cannot assume they are adjacent, sorry.  I gave a simple list but the actual one is much bigger.

Comment: @James P. Wright: In that case all names need to be remembered, not just the last one. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: I realize that LINQ is just pretty Lambda's but I am allowed to use LINQ.  Your solution would work, but my solution fits cleaner into my existing code.  Thank you anyway!